# Can't install eva-icons to Vue-cli project

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I've installed eva-icons to my Vue-cli project, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

---

### main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import * as eva from 'eva-icons'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(eva)

new Vue({
    eva,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

### package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.3.2",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vuemerang": "^1.9.2",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  }

}
```

Comment: And what is the problem you're facing? (any error messages...?)

Comment: no errors. Icons just doesn't show up